# Picking the right type of relationship using Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

I have three tables in my database.

**Posts**

**Authors**

**Categories**

When viewing an **Author** page I want to be able to view all of the author's **Posts** and also the **category** of the post.

When viewing a **Category** index page I want to be able to view all of the **Posts** for that category and also include the **Author** with each Post.

When viewing a **Post** I want to be able to include the **Category** and **Author**

What type of relationship can I use to achieve this?

One to one, One to Many, Many to many, or polymorphic

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your relations like this:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public funcion category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }

    public funcion author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}

class Author extends Eloquent {

    public funcion posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

}

class Category extends Eloquent {

    public funcion posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

}
```

And then use them this way:

```
$author = Author::find(1);

foreach($author->posts as $post)
{
    echo $post->title;
    echo $post->author->name;
}

$category = Category::find(1);

foreach($category->posts as $post)
{
    echo $post->title;
    echo $post->author->name;
}

$post = Post::find(1);

echo $post->category->title;
echo $post->author->name;
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help. For this to work my posts table needs to have the category_id and author_id columns, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but if they don't follow this pattern, you can set a field name on hasMany and belongsTo.

Answer (score -1):

I have done something like this :

db table =

users : id name
debates : id post user_id

now in model

```
class User extends SentryUserModel {


        public function debates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Debate', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Debate extends Eloquent {
    public function user()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id');
    }

}
```

now in query

```
$debate= Debate::find(1);

echo $debates->user->name;
echo $debates->user->id;
```

it is giving a null result.

Changing this two solve the problem . (Do now know why we cant use foreign key here. If anyone know this please do inform ).

class User extends SentryUserModel {

```
    public function debates()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Debate');
}
```

}
and

```
class Debate extends Eloquent {
    public function user()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```